plotting a surface in python revolving a 1D function from data
I have a dataset of points representing a radial density f(r) and its corresponding r values (basically I have two arrays).  I would like to plot a surface in matplolib out of these points making a rotation around the central axis since f(r) has cylindrical symmetry, but I really can't figure out the way to do that. If anyone has ideas it would be really helpful!
I tried using meshgrid, but I'm no expert with python 3d plotting.

Well, I did it! Probably it's not the most elegant solution, but it works. Here's how I did it.
In this case, I read the input data from a csv file and I already know that len(r_data) == len(fr_data) which are just two simple lists.
import numpy as np
r = r_data   
fr= fr_data
p = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 50)
R, P = np.meshgrid(r, p)
X, Y = R*np.cos(P), R*np.sin(P)
Z = []
for theta in p:
   Z.append(fr)


r = r makes no sense...

also, what is fr. it is not defined...

finally, need the import numpy as np.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

thanks for the corrections, I modified my answer to clarify it. Hope it is now acceptable.
